# Can scanning I2C bus cause the OS to lock?

Tags: linux-kernel, i2c

Our product is a specialized device running minimal Ubuntu. Our C++ application on the device periodically scans I2C bus to detect if any new monitor/projector/etc. has been connected. This generally works well. However, once in two to three weeks, we see a random freeze.

As it happens randomly, we cannot consistently reproduce it.

From coding perspective, I essentially scan /dev/i2c-* files, `open()` the file, and try to read first 128 bytes using `ioctl()`.

I guess we do something similar to what Linux tool `i2cdetect` does. From the manpage on `i2cdtect,` it states that "read byte" is known to lock SMBus on various write-only chips. Wondering if anyone knows this could be the problem we are running into. Regards.

Comment: I2C is not a type of the bus you may read anything at anytime. Even manual of the mentioned i2ctools tells that it might break a bus and only full controller reset can be used for recovery. Smells like a kernel driver at least is needed, but in any case i2c was **never** designed as **full hot pluggable** bus.

Comment: Thank you for your help Andy.  I need a reliable way to detect any new monitor/projector being connected and to obtain its edid information. Can you suggest me some other reliable method to obtain edid.